# Array Adapter showing null, Setup appears correct?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have been searching for an answer to this for the past few hours, but time is limited and I need to get this functional so that another member of my team can complete a project milestone. I am implementing a Spinner into a fragment. This spinner is then filled with information pulled from a Firebase database. However, I keep getting a null-pointer exception on speakerPick.setAdapter(sAdapter);

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create__event, container, false);
    saveEvent = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Save_Event);
    etTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_speakerName);
    etLocation = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_Location);
    etWhen = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_When);
    etDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_Date);
    etDetails = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_Details);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Speakers");


    speakerPick.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    saveEvent.setOnClickListener(this);

    mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot childrenSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String name = childrenSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String bio = childrenSnapshot.child("bio").getValue(String.class);
                String photo = childrenSnapshot.child("photoURL").getValue(String.class);
                Speaker newSpeaker = new Speaker(name, bio, photo);
                speakers = new ArrayList<Speaker>();
                speakers.add(newSpeaker);

            }
            speakerPick = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_Speakers);
            sAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, speakers);
            sAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            speakerPick.setAdapter(sAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    return view;
}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
        Process: bwastedsoftware.district_7570_conference, PID: 23860
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setAdapter(AbsSpinner.java:115)
                                                                                          at android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(Spinner.java:508)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.setAdapter(AppCompatSpinner.java:389)
                                                                                          at bwastedsoftware.district_7570_conference.Create_EventFragment$1.onDataChange(Create_EventFragment.java:79)
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: "The error line is 79" ... ummm... you do not expect us to count, or do you?

Comment: Add error from logcat

Comment: Apologies, I had to post quickly, and head home. Didn't realize the numbers didn't show. I have updated the question, there is now a specific line. Error will be posted right away as well.

Comment: `speakers` is null when you instantiate the `Adapter`, so the `Adapter`'s `List` field remains null, and it throws that NPE when it calls `size()` on it after you set the `Adapter` on the `Spinner`. Move `speakers = new ArrayList<Speaker>();` to before `sAdapter = new ArrayAdapter...`.

Comment: Unfortunately @Mike M., this did not solve the problem. Question: can the array adapter contain an object that contains multiple strings? As you can see here, a Speaker consists of string name, bio, and photoURL.

Comment: Yes, but `ArrayAdapter` will only display the `Speaker#toString()` return. If you did indeed change your code to instantiate the `List` before the `Adapter`, then the stack trace should've changed.

Comment: @Mike M. , I have updated the code to represent the changes, and provided the latest logcat. The error appears the same, although now when it references line 79, it is pointing to a closing bracket, and not a line of code in particular.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. If that `for` loop doesn't run, then you're going to end up with the same problem. If it does, then you're only going to ever have one item in your `Spinner`. Anyway, if the stack trace points to the wrong line, then you need to clean/rebuild your project.

Comment: @Mike M. , I think I understand. I actually got it working, there were two problems: First, the DataListener stuff always returned null, because of the way one of my team stored things in the database. After that, the clean was the trick, It showed me where the real error was. When moving things around after being given the wrong error I had accidentally messed up my instantiation. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have defined the array list

sAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, speakers);

speakers is an array list with null pointer exception

Define speakers arraylist string

```
     ArrayList<Speakers> speakers = new List<Speakers>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, as It turns out, my logcat was pointing to the wrong line of error, and I had my instantiation right at the very start, I messed it up trying to squash the null pointer. I also had to fix my firebase call. I appreciate it.